# how to tSUM AS column in mysql query?

Tags: mysql, database, inner-join

I need SUM of last AS column PROFIT, purch_price and forth column Price, i tried few things group by stock.id etc but it is not giving me same answer. please let me know how to take their sum.

```
SELECT
    jobc_consumble.Stock_id,
    jobc_consumble.issued_qty,
    jobc_consumble.total,
    p_purch_stock.Price,
    p_purch_stock.Price * jobc_consumble.issued_qty AS "purch_price",
    jobc_consumble.total -(SELECT   purch_price) AS "profit"

FROM
    jobc_consumble
INNER JOIN p_purch_stock ON jobc_consumble.stock_id = p_purch_stock.stock_id
WHERE
        DATE_FORMAT(
        jobc_consumble.issue_time,
        '%Y-%m-%d'
    ) BETWEEN '2018-07-03' AND '2018-07-03'
```

OUTPUT:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLK7v.png)

what i need it total of like this:

sum of PROFIT: 1105

sum of purch_price: 11000

Comment: Your query is pretty hard to follow.  It would be easier to help you if you posted sample data for the two tables involved along with the output you expect.

Comment: sir please check the image as output, query is working fine but don't know how to take sum of profit. :(

Comment: Please include sample data, table definitions and expected output in your question preferably in textual format or better to use any online tool like http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Hi. What did you learn about using SUM from your research? What simpler query can you use SUM in? Please read & act on [ask] & the downvote arrow mouseover text. Why did googling your title (even with its typo) not help? PS Use text, not images/links, for text.